# Retaining Session in Apache loadbalancer

Tags: php, apache

i have set the following in my proxy_balancer.conf , the server is creating cookie just fine but the server still switches with every refresh or redirect. what am i doing wrong?

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
ServerName mantra.inn650
RewriteEngine On
Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/"    env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>

BalancerMember http://10.6.2.2 route=1
BalancerMember http://10.6.2.3 route=2
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://forumcluster/

ProxyPreserveHost on
<Proxy *>
 Order deny,allow
 Allow from all
</Proxy>

ServerName blog.mantra.inn650
RewriteEngine On
Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
<Proxy balancer://blogcluster>

BalancerMember http://10.6.2.2 route=1
BalancerMember http://10.6.2.3 route=2
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / balancer://blogcluster/
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://forumcluster/

ProxyPreserveHost on
<Proxy *>
 Order deny,allow
 Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing:

`ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID` in your `<Proxy balancer://...>` directive.

From the docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html

Comment: Thanks man, i had removed that line as i thought i was for the other method i was trying earlier, my bad :)